# How can I filter a sub-array?

Tags: linked-list, functional-programming, elixir

I'm working in Elixir, but this question should be applicable in any functional language. Given an array of JSON that may contain a sub-array of JSON, I would like to return

1. Elements of the sub-array that contain a particular value
2. The outer array if there is at least one element remaining in the sub-array

For example, given JSON input

```
decisions = [%{
  "name" => "Only for B",
  "chance" => 0,
  "modifiers" => [%{
    "position" => 0,
    "match" => "B",
    "weight" => 0
  },
  %{
    "position" => 0,
    "match" => "C",
    "weight" => 1
  }
]
}]
```

I would like to get output

```
expected_result = [%{
  "name" => "Only for B",
  "chance" => 0,
  "modifiers" => [%{
    "position" => 0,
    "match" => "B",
    "weight" => 0
  }]
}]
```

By removing elements that do not have weight 0.
I'm currently getting back

```
actual_result = [[%{
  "position" => 0,
  "match" => "B",
  "weight" => 0
}]]
```

Which is removing the outer array.

**Current Code**

```
  def modifiers_with_certainty(decisions) do
    Enum.map(decisions, fn decision ->
      Enum.filter(decision["modifiers"], fn modifier ->
        modifier["weight"] == 0
      end)
    end)
  end
```

The inner enum is filtering the correct elements, but I'm uncertain how to also return the top level. I have also tried using filter instead of map for the outer, but then the inner loop doesn't filter anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fun way to do it with a couple of [comprehensions](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1):

```elixir
for %{"modifiers" => modifiers} = decision <- decisions,
    modifiers = for(%{"weight" => 0} = modifier <- modifiers, do: modifier),
    modifiers != [] do
  %{decision | "modifiers" => modifiers}
end
```

You can use [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) for the internal comprehension if you prefer:

```elixir
for %{"modifiers" => modifiers} = decision <- decisions,
    modifiers = Enum.filter(modifiers, &(&1["weight"] == 0)),
    modifiers != [] do
  %{decision | "modifiers" => modifiers}
end
```

Comment: At the time of posting, this is the only answer that satisfies point 2 in the question 

Answer (score 3):

[`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html), the greatest, but also the most underrated, feature of [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is your friend here. By using `Access` with [`Kernel.update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#update_in/3) this becomes a trivial oneliner.

```elixir
update_in(decisions, [Access.all(), "modifiers"],
  &Enum.filter(&1, fn e -> e["weight"] == 0 end))

#⇒ [
#   %{
#     "chance" => 0,
#     "modifiers" => [%{"match" => "B", "position" => 0, "weight" => 0}],
#     "name" => "Only for B"
#   }
# ]
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the case where there are no `0` weight modifiers. In that case it still returns the outer element with an empty `modifiers` list.

Comment: Which is the correct behaviour IMHO :)

Comment: Point 2 in the question states: "The outer array if there is at least one element remaining in the sub-array"

Comment: Uhoh. My bad, but still, I’d stick to `Access`. If empty modifiers should be discarded, do `update_in` on the above level. The main advantage of `Access` is that it’d work without any significant changes with a structure having this substructure on the deeply nested level. Also, I consider myself an ambassador of `Access` :))

Answer (score 1):

The `update_in/3` answer is probably the best and most compact way, but here are alternatives using `Enum.map/2` and `Enum.filter/2` based on the original code.

The function passed to `Enum.map/2` should basically return a map with the new modifiers.

After computing the new modifiers, you could replace them using [`Map.replace!/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Map.html#replace!/3).

```elixir
Enum.map(decisions, fn decision ->
  modifiers = Enum.filter(decision["modifiers"], & &1["weight"] == 0)
  Map.replace!(decision, "modifiers", modifiers)
end)
```

You could also do the filtering within [`Map.update!/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Map.html#update!/3).

```elixir
Enum.map(decisions, fn decision ->
  Map.update!(decision, "modifiers", fn modifiers ->
    Enum.filter(modifiers, & &1["weight"] == 0)
  end)
end)
```

Comment: I tend to always stick to `Access` whenever possible (and when the performance is not super-important) because it would work without issues even on the 42nd level of nesting.